# How to ignore a file from being type checked?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given I have the following three files:

index.js

```
// @ts-check
const NODE_MAJOR_VERSION = process.versions.node.split('.')[0];

const dependency = NODE_MAJOR_VERSION < 12 
  ? require('./legacy.js') 
  : require('./current.js');

dependency("hello world");
```

legacy.js

```
// @ts-check
module.exports = () => { /* some code for old node versions only */ }
```

current.js

```
// @ts-check
module.exports = () => { /* some code for newer node versions only */ }
```

I would like to check my code for both cases (`node < 12` and `node >= 12`).

My idea was to have two `tsconfig.json` files and to run the type checking twice with different `@types/node` versions installed. For example:

```sh
npm install `@types/node@12.0.0`
tsc -p tsconfig.old.json
npm install `@types/node@latest`
tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to exclude `current.js` from being type checked as it is required by `index.js`.

So far I tried:

tsconfig.json

```
   exclude: [ "current.js" ]
```

However it is still telling me that `current.js` includes type errors once I run `tsc`.